# How to debug "SQL(query) error or missing database" in an Android app?

Tags: android, kotlin

```
10-02 01:31:57.697 22242-22242/com.example.android.mynotes E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.android.mynotes, PID: 22242
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10826)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697) 
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10826) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "EXISTName": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTName(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,TitleTEXT,DescriptionTEXT);
    #################################################################
    Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
    Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
       (near "EXISTName": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTName(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,TitleTEXT,DescriptionTEXT);)
    #################################################################
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1058)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:623)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1812)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1743)
        at com.example.android.mynotes.DbManager$DatabaseHelperNotes.onCreate(DbManager.kt:32)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:251)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
        at com.example.android.mynotes.DbManager.<init>(DbManager.kt:22)
        at com.example.android.mynotes.AddNotes.BtnAdd(AddNotes.kt:19)
           ... 12 more
```

Comment: When presenting logs, please (a) add some paragraph text to explain what they are, (b) use the block formatting tool, and (c) un-indent them so they are readable. Android Java logs are notorious for putting content 20+ tabs to the right.

Comment: `EXISTName`, `TitleTEXT`, and `DescriptionTEXT` would appear to be missing space characters in the middle.

Comment: Thank you @halfer for editing . I will keep these things in mind next time .

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTName
```

You are missing a space between the keyword `EXIST` and the table name `Name`.

Comment: @QudsiaMehmood: Then you are getting other errors. Feel free to ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where you provide a [mcve], showing the complete Java stack trace and your Java code referenced in that stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the block of code in a try-catch block and then put debug point on it and determine the exception and correct it.

e.g

```
try
{
 //block of code in which you have an error or you want to debug
}
catch(e: Exception)
{
  // you can use log for seeing error or you can simply view errors by 
  //putting debug point and pressing alt+mouse_left_click after executing 
  //line to get value of exception instance
}
```